# How would you explain the ribbon menu sections?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, ribbon

For SharePoint 2013 is this the correct terminology to explain the ribbon menu?

The areas that are labeled New, Manage, Hierarchy, Actions, Share & Track and Workflows are the title section in the ribbon menu and the upper sections are the functions. Is this correct?

[image: screenshot of the ribbon menu]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **Ribbon** implementation is not just restricted to Sharepoint but is part of the Office UI that launched with this new design.

The ribbon is defined by the **Ribbon.xml** and as per the [XML schema](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa942866.aspx#Anchor_3)

```
Ribbon --> Tab --> Groups --> Actions/Controls
```

So the New, Manage, Heirarchy etc. would be **groups** and the individual icons, the **Actions/Controls**.